# How to call function based on scroll bar click?

Tags: php, jquery, html

I am having the Div with scroll bar.When User clicks the scroll bar I need to call the function based on the scroll bar click.How can I make a call?

1. I am using Jquery in the client and using the PHP in the server side.
2. I know how to make ajax calls and etc.Only think is I need to make this call when scroll bar is clicked in that div.

Is it possible to make the ID for the scroll bar in that div.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can bind to the `scroll` event, it's not fired when the user clicks the scroll-bar but it is **fired when the scroll-bar moves for any reason**:

```
//wait for document.ready to fire, meaning the DOM is ready to be manipulated
$(function () {

    //bind an event handler to the `scroll` event for your div element
    $('#my-scroll-div').on('scroll.test-scroll', function () {

        //you can do your AJAX call in here, I would set a flag to only allow it to run once, because the `scroll` event fires A LOT when scrolling occurs
    });
});
```

Note that `.on()` is new in jQuery 1.7 and in this case is the same as using `.bind()`.

To set a flag like I suggest above:

```
$(function () {

    var AJAX_flag = true;
    $('#my-scroll-div').on('scroll.test-scroll', function () {
        if (AJAX_flag === true) {
            AJAX_flag = false;
            $(this).off('scroll.test-scroll');
            $.ajax({...});
        }
    });
});
```

### Update

The best solution to adding event handlers to dynamically created elements is to bind to them before adding them to the DOM:

```
function scroll_func () {
    var AJAX_flag = true;
    $(this).on('scroll.test-scroll', function () {
        if (AJAX_flag === true) {
            AJAX_flag = false;
            $(this).off('scroll.test-scroll');//unbind the event handler since we're done with it
            $.ajax({...});
        }
    });
}

$.ajax({
    ...
    success : function (data) {

        //note that this selector will have to change to find the proper elements for you, if you are unsure how to select, start by seeing what data is by doing a `console.log(data);`
        $(data).find('#my-scroll-div').on('scroll', scroll_func).appendTo('#container-element');
    }
});
```

Comment: But you must be careful with this solution. As he has said it gets fired when the scroll-bar moves for any reason. That means also when the scrolling is initiated by JavaScript, or when not the scroll-bar itself is used, but the arrows to scroll, or the page-up, page-down key.

Comment: A good point to re-iterate, I **bolded** the text in my answer.

Comment: @Jasper @Sven Bieder Hi friends thanks for the help.It calls when I make the sample page.But I am loading the content in ajax.At that time even I scrolled  the scroll its not calling.I used the `live` also.But its not worked.Any ideas?

Comment: @svk I **updated** my answer with an example of how to bind to elements before adding them to the DOM.

Comment: @Jasper I changed your code little bit and its start working.The changes I made is `$("#container-element").append(data).find('#my-scroll-div').on('scroll', scroll_func);`